# If 連用形 can replace て-form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

I wonder if the て in 僕を飼いならしてたいみたいだ can be removed? Because I think ならし is the 連用形 of ならす, so it can also used to link two verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be removed but doing so would change the meaning of the sentence.

飼いならしてたい is a contracted form of 飼いならして**い**たい. Whoever is the subject wants to be in a **state** where, depending on context, they either continue the act of taming "me" or keep "me" tamed.

飼いならしたい would mean they want to tame "me". It's a one-time action or change, rather than a state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
You mean that the full sentence is 僕を飼いならしていたいみたいだ  and ていたい means ‘in the state of stagnant’,  right?
And I also find that in 僕を飼いならしてたいみたいだ,  the たいcan be translated as ’want’.
So I wonder if the both translations are correct?
The full sentence is ‘まだこの世界は 僕を飼いならしてたいみたいだ’.

Comment: @Shawmorn - What both translations? And I didn't say "stagnant". In general, 〜ていたい is the たい-form, which expresses desire, of 〜ている, which consists of the て-form of a verb and いる as a subsidiary verb. The whole sentence means something like *it seems this world still wants to keep me tamed.*